# How to disable vscode Git changes peek button next to line number

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to disable this feature in VSCode. I often use the code fold button next to the line number, but the Git changes peek button always gets in the way.

The button:

[[image: the button]]

The only way I found to disable it is to turn off Git completely.

Git Enabled setting:

[image: Git Enabled setting]

Is it possible to disable this peek button from showing at all?

Comment: You should report this as a bug in the VSCode Github. If two elements of the UI are conflicting, they'll want to know that so they can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Search the settings for "Diff Decorations Gutter Action" and set to `none`.

Or add this to your settings.json file

```
"scm.diffDecorationsGutterAction": "none"
```

They seem to have fixed the visual indicator since this question was asked, but the actual hit box seems to still extend out over the code folding arrows.